# How to get point cloud from binocular vision

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm looking for a software that can generate point cloud from binocular cameras.

Is there any software provides utilities to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here I find the answer: OpenCV stereo utilities could be a choice.

1) use OpenCV calibration procedure to get the parameters of two cameras

tutorials could be found, [e.g.](http://blog.martinperis.com/2011/01/opencv-stereo-camera-calibration.html)

2) use

```
cvFindStereoCorrespondenceGC()
```

to get the stereo correspondence and depth map.

**What else solutions are there?**